# Fortran intrinsic timing routines, which is better? cpu_time or system_clock

Tags: timer, fortran

When timing a FORTRAN program i usually just use the command `call cpu_time(t)`.
Then i stumbled across `call system_clock([count,count_rate,count_max])` which seems to do the same thing. However, in a more difficult manor.
My knowledge of these come from: [Old Intel documentation](http://www.fkf.mpg.de/edv/docs/intel_composer/Documentation/en_US/compiler_f/main_for/lref_for/source_files/rfcpu_tm.htm).
I wasn't able to find it on Intel's homepage. See my markup below.

1. Which is the more accurate, or are they similar?
2. Do one of them count cache misses (or other of the sorts) and the other not, or do any of them?
3. Or is the only difference being the marked thing in my markup below?

Those are my questions, below i have supplied a code for you to see some timings and usages. They have showed me that they are very similar in output and thus seem to be similar in implementation.
I should note that i will probably always stick with `cpu_time`, and that i don't really need more precise timings.

In the below code i have tried to compare them. (i have also tried more elaborate things, but will not supply in order to keep brevity)
So basically my result is that:

- `cpu_time`

  1. Is easier to use, you don't need the initialization calls
  2. Direct time in a difference
  3. Should also be compiler specific, but there is no way to see the precision. (the norm is milliseconds)
  4. **Is sum of thread time. I.e. not recommended for parallel runs.**
- `system_clock`

  1. Needs pre-initialization.
  2. After-process, in form of a divide. (small thing, but nonetheless a difference)
  3. Is compiler specific. On my PC the following was found:

     - **Intel 12.0.4** uses a count rate of 10000, due to the `INTEGER` precision.
     - **gcc-4.4.5** uses 1000, do not know how this differentiates
  4. Is prone to encounter *wraparounds*, i.e. if `c1 > c2`, due to `count_max`
  5. **Is time from one standard time. Thus this will yield the actual time of one thread and not the sum.**

Code:

```
PROGRAM timer
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL :: t1,t2,rate 
  INTEGER :: c1,c2,cr,cm,i,j,n,s
  INTEGER , PARAMETER :: x=20000,y=15000,runs=1000
  REAL :: array(x,y),a_diff,diff

  ! First initialize the system_clock
  CALL system_clock(count_rate=cr)
  CALL system_clock(count_max=cm)
  rate = REAL(cr)
  WRITE(*,*) "system_clock rate ",rate

  diff = 0.0
  a_diff = 0.0
  s = 0
  DO n = 1 , runs
     CALL CPU_TIME(t1)
     CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(c1)
     FORALL(i = 1:x,j = 1:y)
        array(i,j) = REAL(i)*REAL(j) + 2
     END FORALL
     CALL CPU_TIME(t2)
     CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(c2)
     array(1,1) = array(1,2)     
     IF ( (c2 - c1)/rate < (t2-t1) ) s = s + 1
     diff = (c2 - c1)/rate - (t2-t1) + diff
     a_diff = ABS((c2 - c1)/rate - (t2-t1)) + a_diff
  END DO

  WRITE(*,*) "system_clock : ",(c2 - c1)/rate
  WRITE(*,*) "cpu_time     : ",(t2-t1)
  WRITE(*,*) "sc < ct      : ",s,"of",runs
  WRITE(*,*) "mean diff    : ",diff/runs
  WRITE(*,*) "abs mean diff: ",a_diff/runs
END PROGRAM timer
```

To complete i here give the output from my Intel 12.0.4 and gcc-4.4.5 compiler.

- `Intel 12.0.4` with `-O0`

  ```
  system_clock rate    10000.00    
  system_clock :    2.389600    
  cpu_time     :    2.384033    
  sc < ct      :            1 of        1000
  mean diff    :   4.2409324E-03
  abs mean diff:   4.2409897E-03

  real    42m5.340s
  user    41m48.869s
  sys 0m12.233s
  ```
- `gcc-4.4.5` with `-O0`

  ```
  system_clock rate    1000.0000    
  system_clock :    1.1849999    
  cpu_time     :    1.1840820    
  sc < ct      :          275 of        1000  
  mean diff    :   2.05709646E-03  
  abs mean diff:   2.71424348E-03  

  real    19m45.351s  
  user    19m42.954s  
  sys 0m0.348s
  ```

Thanks for reading...

Comment: Using `INTEGER(8)` for `SYSTEM_CLOCK` in gfortran increases `count_max` significantly, should be like this for some other compilers as well.

Answer (score 27):

These two intrinsics report different types of time.   system_clock reports "wall time" or elapsed time.  cpu_time reports time used by the CPU.   On a multi-tasking machine these could be very different, e.g., if your process shared the CPU equally with three other processes and therefore received 25% of the CPU and used 10 cpu seconds, it would take about 40 seconds of actual elapsed or wall clock time.

Comment: As i have also written in my question this is also what i consider to be the main difference.  

But are there other more subtle ones?

Answer (score 5):

cpu_time() usually has a resolution of about 0.01 second on Intel compatible CPUs.  This means that a smaller time interval may count as zero time.
Most current compilers for linux make the resolution of system_clock() depend on the data types of the arguments, so integer(int64) will give better than 1 microsecond resolution, as well as permitting counting over a significant time interval.
gfortran for Windows was changed recently (during 2015) so as to make system_clock() equivalent to query_performance calls.  ifort Windows, however, still shows about 0.01 resolution for system_clock, even after omp_get_wtime was changed to use query_performance.
I would discount previous comments about measuring cpu_time or system_clock resolution in clock ticks, particularly if that may be thought to relate to CPU or data buss ticks, such as rdtsc instruction could report.

Answer (score 3):

I find `itime` (see [gfortran manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ITIME.html)) to be a good alternative to `system_clock` for timing fortran programs. It is very easy to use:

```
integer, dimension(3) :: time
call itime(time)
print *, 'Hour:  ', time(1)
print *, 'Minute:', time(2)
print *, 'Second:', time(3)
```

Comment: The problem is that it is a non-standard extension.

Comment: It might be non-standard (GNU extension), but it is supported by many compilers. I tested and found it working with ifort, pgf90, sunf90 and g95.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Also, the question wasn't asking for it at all.

Comment: That's a valid point. It might have been better to mention `itime` in a comment than in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find secnds() to be the easiest way to get wall time. Its usage is almost identical to cpu_time().

```
real(8)::t1,delta
t1=secnds(0.0)
!Do stuff
delta=seconds(t1)
```

Comment: Is this an intrinsic function for all compilers?
So what difference does this have compared to the others?

Comment: It does not appear to be an intrinsic function for gfortran

Comment: I now use `system_clock`.