# Sleep in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

Does anyone know of an way to sleep for a given number of milliseconds in Fortran?  I do not want to use non-portable system calls so anything intrinsic to Fortran or C libraries would be preferred.

Comment: There is a 'sleep' subroutine that takes a number of seconds as an argument but I'm not sure where that's coming from (wrapper to C function?).  It seems to work fine for what I'm intending.  I'm using the Intel Fortran Compiler 12 on a PC.

Comment: I just ran across a Fortran program that uses a (non-standard) call system(char_arg) that accesses system with no cpu overhead. Tried it out with pgf90, ifort, and gfortran, all are fine with it. So, one could do something like call system('sleep '//number_of_seconds_string) to obtain a sleep function. Did not have a chance to test this with other compilers.

Comment: I think the `sleep` subroutine @BrianTriplett talks is a gnu extension, so I don't know if it fits the being portable requirement

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the Fortran ISO C Binding to use the C library sleep to sleep in units of seconds:

```
   module Fortran_Sleep

   use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_int

   implicit none

   interface

      !  should be unsigned int ... not available in Fortran
      !  OK until highest bit gets set.
      function FortSleep (seconds)  bind ( C, name="sleep" )
          import
          integer (c_int) :: FortSleep
          integer (c_int), intent (in), VALUE :: seconds
      end function FortSleep

   end interface

end module Fortran_Sleep


program test_Fortran_Sleep

   use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_int

   use Fortran_Sleep

   implicit none

   integer (c_int) :: wait_sec, how_long

   write (*, '( "Input sleep time: " )', advance='no')
   read (*, *) wait_sec
   how_long = FortSleep ( wait_sec )

   write (*, *) how_long

   stop

end program test_Fortran_Sleep
```

Comment: do you think the 'sleep' function provided inside of Intel Fortran is basically doing the same thing you provided above?

Comment: Yes, the functionally is probably the same. A similar subroutine is available in gfortran.   This is an extension that might not be part of some other compiler.

Comment: Hi, in Linux I could use this and it works fine. In Windows and using MinGW, when compiling it complains that it cannot find Sleep function. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: This solution is not portable across OSes. (*nix only, I believe.) @milancurcic 's answer below should work across all OSes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Fortran standard intrinsic functions to do this without C binding:

```
program sleep
!===============================================================================
implicit none
character(len=100) :: arg ! input argument character string
integer,dimension(8) :: t ! arguments for date_and_time
integer :: s1,s2,ms1,ms2  ! start and end times [ms]
real :: dt                ! desired sleep interval [ms]
!===============================================================================
! Get start time:
call date_and_time(values=t)
ms1=(t(5)*3600+t(6)*60+t(7))*1000+t(8)

! Get the command argument, e.g. sleep time in milliseconds:
call get_command_argument(number=1,value=arg)
read(unit=arg,fmt=*)dt

do ! check time:
  call date_and_time(values=t)
  ms2=(t(5)*3600+t(6)*60+t(7))*1000+t(8)
  if(ms2-ms1>=dt)exit
enddo
!===============================================================================
endprogram sleep
```

Assuming the executable is slp:

```
~$ time slp 1234

real        0m1.237s
user        0m1.233s
sys         0m0.003s
```

Add a special case to this program if you are worried it will break around midnight :)

Comment: Which reminds me. This approach should definitely not be used if you need cpu time during sleep period. I assumed you do not this for long waits for remote data. If you do, you are far better off using a shell wrapper, because example above  is cpu intensive.

Comment: This answer is definitely more portable than the accepted answer.

Comment: It is *slightly* more portable, but it is busy waiting, not proper sleeping, so the accepted answer is the right one to be accepted.

Comment: This is busy waiting, this can't really be considered as sleep.

Answer (score -1):

```
      ! This is another option of making your fortran code to wait for x seconds
       Integer :: iStart, iNew
       Real*8 :: rWait, rDT
      ! rWait: seconds that you want to wait for; you can also set this as an (IN)
      ! variable if this code goes into a subroutine that is developed to be called 
      ! from any part of the program.
      rWait = 1.d0; rDT = 0.d0
      call system_clock (iStart)
      do while (rDT <= rWait)
          call system_clock (iNew)
          rDT = floatj (iNew - iStart) / 10000.d0
      enddo
```

Comment: system_clock is still non-portable. It may behave differently on different systems/different compilers. [Check out this answer already.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878246/fortran-intrinsic-timing-routines-which-is-better-cpu-time-or-system-clock)

Comment: It is portable, but one has to query the clock rate and use the value one gets. Also, this is just *busy wating* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting, not proper sleeping.