# programming issue with openmp

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am having issues with openmp, described as follows:

I have the serial code like this

```
subroutine ...  
  ...  
  do i=1,N
    ....  
  end do  
end subroutine ...
```

and the openmp code is

```
subroutine ...  
  use omp_lib  
  ...  
  call omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_num_procs())
  !$omp parallel do  
  do i=1,N
    ....  
  end do  
  !$omp end parallel do  
end subroutine ...
```

No issues with compiling, however when I run the program, there are two major issues compared to the result of serial code:

1. The program is running even slower than the serial code (which supposedly do matrix multiplications (matmul) in the do-loop
2. The numerical accuracy seems to have dropped compared to the serial code (I have a check for it)

Any ideas what might be going on?
Thanks,
Xiaoyu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fortran Parallel Programming‎](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465101/fortran-parallel-programming)

Comment: Or, even better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878246/fortran-intrinsic-timing-routines-which-is-better-cpu-time-or-system-clock

Answer (score 1):

In case of an parallelization using OpenMP, you will need to specify the number of threads your program is to use. You can do so by using the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, e.g. calling your program by means of

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=5 ./myprogram
```

to execute it using 5 threads.

Alternatively, you may set the number of threads at runtime `omp_set_num_threads` ([documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fset_005fnum_005fthreads.html#omp_005fset_005fnum_005fthreads)).

**Side Notes**

1. Don't forget to set private variables, if there are any within the loop!
   Example:

   > !$omp parallel do private(prelimRes)
   >   do i = 1, N
   >     prelimRes = myFunction(i)
   >     res(i) = prelimRes + someValue
   >   end do
   >   !$omp end parallel do

   Note how the variable `prelimRes` is declared `private` so that every thread has its own workspace.
2. Depending on what you actually do within the loop (i.e. use OpenBLAS), your results may indeed vary (variations should be smaller than 1e-8 with regard to double precision variables) due to the differing, parellel processing.
3. If you are unsure about what is happening, you should check the CPU load using `htop` or a similar program while your program is running.

**Addendum: Setting the number of threads to automatically match the number of CPUs**
If you would like to use the maximum number of useful threads, e.g. use as many threads as there are CPUs, you can do so by using (just like you stated in your question):

```
subroutine ...  
    use omp_lib  
    ...  
    call omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_num_procs())
    !$omp parallel do
    do i=1,N
        ....  
    end do  
    !$omp end do  
    !$omp end parallel
end subroutine ...
```

Comment: @Rain That is indeed possible. You should watch out for the result of `omp_get_num_procs()`. Afaik, you should only use this command within a omp-environment if you'd like to obtain reliable results.

Comment: @Rain If I understand you correctly, you already do set the number of processes (but it does not seem to work)? Have you checked the other two hints in my posting?

Comment: I set the number of processes as modified in the main context, and checked that when the program is running, the system monitor shows 4 threads being used by the program

Comment: @Rain I assume you only have 4 CPUs? The problem with using the command the way you do is that you never actually assign a number of threads to your program.

Comment: I have 2 CPUS on my laptop. Intel has this hyperthreading technique which will split it into 4. I don't understand your answer as to my problem with programming. Is it that the do-loop is not split evenly to the four threads?

Comment: @Rain Thought so.. you should not use the command `omp_get_num_procs()` and set the number of threads explicitly to 2 (everything else will jam your CPUs). Avoid setting the number of threads the way you do it right now. A non-equal splitting of the `do`-loop is additionally possibly, that is a matter of optionally using `schedule(...)`.

Comment: I solved the issue of data accuracy, turns out I forgot to declare private variables for some internal parameters... The program is still quite slow as compared to serial code. I suspect it has to do with putting the parallel code in a subroutine that is called frequently. What do you think?

Comment: @Rain I'd need to see some more code to be able to answer this. Maybe start a separate/new question on this? As soon as you achieve 20 reputation, we can also enter a chat and discuss this issue in detail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60259/discussion-between-pystarter-and-rain).