# Benchmarking fortran loop

Tags: fortran, benchmarking, fortran2008

I need to benchmark a part of a fortran program to understand and quantify the impact of specific changes (in order to make the code more maintainable we'd like to make it more OO, taking advantage of function pointers for example).

I have a loop calling several times the same subroutines to perform computations on finite elements. I want to see the impact of using function pointers instead of just hard-coded functions.

```
do i=1,n_of_finite_elements
   ! Need to benchmark execution time of this code
end do
```

What would be a simple way to get the execution time of such a loop, and format it in a nic way ?

Comment: Are you looking for something that profiles the code or just coarse timing of how long it takes as a whole? What OS and compiler are you using? for a simple way to check things by hand see [`CPU_TIME`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CPU_005fTIME.html). Also [this question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/6812/fortran-best-way-to-time-sections-of-your-code) might be useful.

Comment: @Gabe Please, don't use `CPU_TIME`. It is not really suited for time measurement, especially in [parallel programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465101/fortran-parallel-programming). Instead, use `SYSTEM_CLOCK`.

Comment: Well timing as a whole, but benchmarking is (I hope) not just about taking note of system time. For example the [ruby benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) provides interesting metrics like user, system and total time, formats this in a very nice display, and even explains what precautions to take when benchmarking.

Comment: This site is not for software recommendations, they are on-topic at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Profiling of Fortran code is a very broad topic, you can find many articles about it, but you can't put it all in short answer here. Mostly the same profilers as for C and C++ can be used also for Fortran.

Comment: @Alexander point taken, although I did mean it just as a quick and rough option while linking to more detailed solutions :) but you're right, I wasn't really thinking about the possibility of parallel code, and should keep SYSTEM_CLOCK more in mind. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

I have a github project that measures the performance of passing various arrays at https://github.com/jlokimlin/array_passing_performance.git

It uses the CpuTimer derived data type from https://github.com/jlokimlin/cpu_timer.git.

Usage:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: &
    wp => REAL64, &
    ip => INT32

use type_CpuTimer, only: &
    CpuTimer

type (CpuTimer) :: timer
real (wp)       :: wall_clock_time
real (wp)       :: total_processor_time
integer (ip)    :: units = 0 ! (optional argument) = 0 for seconds, or 1 for minutes, or 2 for hours

! Starting the timer
call timer%start()

do i = 1, n

    !...some big calculation...

end do

! Stopping the timer
call timer%stop()

! Reading the time
wall_clock_time = timer%get_elapsed_time(units)

total_processor_time = timer%get_total_cpu_time(units)

! Write time stamp to standard output
call timer%print_time_stamp()

! Write compiler info to standard output
call timer%print_compiler_info()
```

Comment: It's interesting and can be of good use, but hardly covers the whole broad topic from the question.

Comment: Well that's actually something like this I wanted. I will try to restrict my question so it matches this answer's scope I guess.

Comment: In that case you can always start with the set of standard intrinsic procedures `system_clock()` and `cpu_time()`, although this package has more features in one object.