# Fortran OpenMP code creating threads but do loops not running in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, gfortran

I have compiled the following code with gfortran (`-fopenmp` flag set), but for the life of me can't work out why the do loops don't run in parallel. I have checked that the threads are created, but yet the code runs sequentially. (Checked CPU load and obviously no improvement in timing.)

```
  use omp_lib

  declarations and do some stuff here

  call OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(6)

  !$OMP PARALLEL default(none) shared(nx,ny,nz,nb,some more variables) private(i,j,k,l)
  print*, 'Hello', omp_get_thread_num()
  !$OMP DO collapse(3)
  do i=1,nx+1,1
    do j=1,ny+1,1
      do k=1,nz+1,1
        do some stuff...
      end do
    end do
  end do
  !$OMP END DO

  !$OMP BARRIER

  !$OMP DO collapse(3)
  do i=1,nx+1,1
    do j=1,ny+1,1
      do k=1,nz+1,1
        grid(7,i,j,k) = 0.
        grid(4:6,i,j,k) = 0.
        do l=1,nb,1
          do some stuff
        end do
        do some stuff
      end do
    end do
  end do
  !$OMP END DO
  !$OMP END PARALLEL
```

I would like the innermost, the l loop, to run in a single thread for each case. As far as I understand it, the `!$OMP DO` construct only parallelises the do loop immediately following the statement (`i` loop), hence why I need the `collapse(3)` statement, to get the other two to also parallelise (`j` and `k`), is this correct?

The output gives the following

```
 Hello           1
 Hello           4
 Hello           5
 Hello           0
 Hello           3
 Hello           2
```

suggesting 6 threads (as requested) have been created, however the following loops run in series, why?
I have tried: using omp parallel do constructs instead; removing all clauses such that variables are shared/private according to default.

I would be very grateful to anyone who can give me some pointers as to where I am going wrong.

Comment: Welcome. Be sure to see the [Tour] and read [ask] when joining StackOverflow. How did you time it? What is `do some stuff`? We usually ask people to provide full working code without such ommisions ([mcve]).

Comment: BTW, forget `OMP BARRIER`, I am yet to see a code where it would be needed or helpful. A barrier is implied in `OMP END DO`.

Comment: Ok, just worked it out thanks to your comment regarding timing. I was dull enough to use cpu_time() to time the program, giving me the sum of time of all threads spent running it. With omp_get_wtime(), it gives me the expected reduction in time. Have taken the comments regarding workable code example on board. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fortran OpenMP program shows no speedup of CPU\_TIME()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465101/fortran-openmp-program-shows-no-speedup-of-cpu-time)